# Div fades opacity out when user scrolls to just before the bottom of each page

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I am currently making a site with an arrow implying the user to scroll down. I have managed to get this code below which gives a very nice fade in and out of the icon but I want to have the icon opacity to start fading away about 300px from the bottom of every page on my site.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $(".down-arrow").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 300);
});
```

Each page is different lengths so if someone could point me in the right direction of getting this animation to apply 300px from the bottom of each page that would be amazing!

Cheers!

Edit - I have made a jsfiddle.net to with the code I am currently using:
https://jsfiddle.net/euty0oon/

Comment: document.body.scrollHeight gives you the scroll height of the document. You can use that in your math to figure out where to start fading.

Comment: Could you create a https://jsfiddle.net or share more code? If it helps this is how you get the height of the document (page) `$(document).height()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/euty0oon/

Comment: First of all, please add jquery reference to your fiddle. And so you want to start fadding if bottom is 300px?

Comment: the jquery is working fine already? but yes I want to make it start fading 300px from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here's `fadeToBottom()` wrapped as a tiny jQuery plugin:

```js
$.fn.fadeToBottom = function(d) {
  var w=$(window), 
      f=()=>{$(this).css({opacity:Math.min($('body')[0].scrollHeight-w.scrollTop()-w.height(),d)/d})};
  if(d)w.on('load scroll resize',f)
}
```

Use as

```js
$('.down-arrow').fadeToBottom(300);
```

Your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/908db9tf/).

---

If you care about page performance, use the version below, (*especially if you use it on more than one element on same page!*) making sure you load Ben Alman's [debounce/throttle](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) first (depends on it):

```js
$.fn.fadeToBottom = function(d) {
  var w=$(window), 
      f=()=>{$(this).css({opacity:Math.min($('body')[0].scrollHeight-w.scrollTop()-w.height(),d)/d})};
  $(this).css({transition:'opacity 42ms'});
  if(d)w.on('load scroll resize',$.throttle(42,f))
}
```